# query_string type query takes a long time to respond, what could be the reason?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ES query that is using `query_string` type query. In one cluster it returns immediately, and in another it takes 30 seconds.
What could be the differences between them? As far as I can tell, both are indexed.

Example query string: `*1073917897* OR *1074016666* OR *1074210535* OR *1074210522* OR *1074146059* OR *1074176205* OR *1073894784* OR *1074171218* OR *1074296680* OR *1074146052* OR *1074011547* OR *1074260323*`
I know that this is not a very good query, but again, in one cluster it responds almost immediately (0.3s) and in the other over 30 seconds.
The faster cluster holds more documents (40M) than the slower cluster (30M)

Comment: it would be interesting to see the complexity of the query, and also if the both clusters are comparable in terms of index mappings, size, and data volume

Comment: @Val I added the data you requested

Comment: Thanks and how do both clusters compare, architecture and configuration wise?

Comment: as far as I know they are the same - those clusters are production and staging, so it should be identical. obviously something is different and I can't figure out what

Comment: Any chance to get the configuration and topology of both because "should" doesn't sound too convincing :-) If you can get the index settings and cluster settings from both cluster, it's easy to compare them, that would be a good start.

Comment: how can i get those?

Comment: `GET <index>/_settings?include_defaults=true` and `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults=true` and also `GET _nodes` so you can compare the topologies of both clusters. There must be differences somewhere

Answer (score 0):

### Here are some best practices to tune the search speed of query_string

> Allowing a wildcard at the beginning of a word (eg "*ing") is
> particularly heavy, because all terms in the index need to be
> examined, just in case they match. Leading wildcards can be disabled
> by setting allow_leading_wildcard to false.
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html
>
> Wildcard searches can be run on individual terms, using ? to replace a
> single character, and * to replace zero or more characters:
>
> qu?ck bro* Be aware that wildcard queries can use an enormous amount
> of memory and perform very badly — just think how many terms need to
> be queried to match the query string "a* b* c*".

```
Pure wildcards \* are rewritten to exists queries for efficiency. As a consequence, the wildcard "field:*" would match documents with an empty value like the following:

{
  "field": ""
}
... and would not match if the field is missing or set with an explicit null value like the following:

{
  "field": null
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-wildcard

Comment: Thanks, I know that `*` wildcards are not fast - but still the question stands - in one cluster it's very fast, and in the second it's slow. both have the same configuration as far as i know

Comment: Check following, 1- hardware, field type, document count

Comment: all the same...

Comment: There must be some differences, once the hardwares are the same but RAID type was the issue for one of my customer. :) I recommend you to check with someone else who has deep knowledge about infrastructure.